# Enabling In-App purchase for custom keyboard iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

I am building a custom keyboard for iOS and I want to know how can I enable in-app purchases for that? The documentation states that I can enable in-app purchases through the containing app, but I am not sure what that means (technically)?

Has anyone built iPhone extensions with in-app purchasing that could give me some guidance?

Answer (score 2):

An extension is bundled with an app. When the user downloads the containing app, the extensions are available for the user to add to their keyboard list, today view, etc. If you want to charge for a keyboard, currently the only way you can do that is by charging for an app that contains a keyboard extension.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it clear, in-app purchases from within any app extension including keyboards are not allowed and will cause your app to fail review. In-app purchases must be done in the container app.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

> 4.4 […] the extensions may not include marketing, advertising, or in-app purchases.