# iOS custom keyboard extensions capabilities

Tags: ios, keyboard, in-app-purchase, uikeyboard

I have a couple of questions about custom keyboard extensions. Can I make a custom keyboard that contains only images(stickers or emoticons)?
And whether it is possible to make the payment of such stickers directly from keyboard, when clicking on the sticker, without transition to the container app (i.e., pressing the sticker should appear popup prompting you to enter data for the in-app purchase)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found this: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

According this rules:

> 25.3 Apps hosting extensions that include marketing, advertising, or **in-app purchases** in their extension view will be rejected
>
> 25.6 Keyboard extensions **must provide Number and Decimal keyboard types** as described in the App Extension Programming Guide or they
> will be rejected
>
> 25.7 Apps offering Keyboard extensions **must provide keyboard functionality (e.g. typed characters)**, have a primary category of
> Utilities and a privacy policy or they will be rejected

So I can't make a keyboard with only images and without 'qwerty' characters. And I can't embed iAP to the keyboard view, only in keyboard's container app.

Answer (score 2):

- Ya It can possible that your `custom keyboard` contains images,But you need `QWERTY` characters too.
- It's not possible to enable the payment in custom keyboard extension,the reason is that under `keyboard Target ->Capabilities -> Enabling Inapp` is not there.

[image]

[image]

It is possible to make a payment in your container app Only,Based on that payment you can make your cu†om keyboard change.

And also refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347018/enabling-in-app-purchase-for-custom-keyboard-ios8) once

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found rules below.